# Trouble with switch2osm tutorial for ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, openstreetmap, mapnik

I'm following [this guide](http://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/manually-building-a-tile-server-12-04/), but when I get to the part where I start the tileserver, an error occurs.

I executed the command `renderd -f -c /usr/local/etc/renderd.conf` on the terminal, but the following message appears:

> "renderd[16156]: An error occurred while loading the map layer 'default': XML document not well formed:
>
> Entity 'datasource-settings' not defined (encountered in file '/path/to/mapnik-style/osm.xml' at line 4060)"

I decided to start the server anyway `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart`

Everything goes fine, no FATAL errors.

I go to localhost/osm_tiles2/0/0/0.png to see if it worked and what happens is:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /osm_tiles2/0/0/0.png was not found on this server.

Comment: Did you create the `datasource-settings.xml.inc` from the template and edit it according to the switch2osm guide?

Answer (score 2):

If you installed osm2pgsql from a package, your import style may be out of date. Make sure you have and use the latest version by [downloading it](https://github.com/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql/blob/master/default.style) to your mapnik-stylesheets directory and adding the --style (or -S) option to your osm2pgsql command to point to this up-to-date file. (Adjust the directory as necessary.)

```
osm2pgsql --style ~/mapnik-stylesheets/default.style --database gis --username gisuser --slim planet-latest.osm.pbf
```